Problem with VS Code not fully utilizing venv virtual environment
When I work with Conda, everything runs smoothly. I create an environment, activate it, and all functionalities work perfectly directly from that environment. However, when using a virtual environment created via venv in VS Code, several functionalities stop working as expected:

Autoformat on save: This feature no longer works.

Running code (F5): Instead of running from the virtual environment, the code runs from the global Python installation.


Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Verified that the correct interpreter is selected (Ctrl + Shift + P -> "Python: Select Interpreter").
Activated the virtual environment manually.
Modified the settings.json file to ensure it points to the correct interpreter and formatter.
Spent hours troubleshooting, even using different GPT-based assistants, but no solution has worked.
From what I can gather, it seems like VS Code isn’t fully utilizing the venv environment even though it appears to be selected and activated.
Has anyone experienced this issue to ensure VS Code dedicates itself to just use the correct venv environment?

when you open .py file, in bottom right section there is interpreter selection. Make sure it matches with one you have when you open terminal and get with which python

You're right. That's one of the first things I check, but the problem still exists
